# product length width height

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

im importing a large csv programmatically and i want to save product length width height and didn't found any post related to this, so:

I tried to:

```
$product->setCustomAttribute('width',(int)$data[22]);
$product->setCustomAttribute('ts_dimensions_width',(int)$data[22]);
```

## from product attributes

```
$product->setData('lenght',$data[21]);
```

Any of these more `logical` ways didn't work.
any ideas?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to discover that the code was right! but in configuration: Stores->Product Attributes, we have to set them to GLOBAL.